# Plot a matrix in Python with custom colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a matrix using pytlot in python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = [
    [1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 0],
    [0, 4, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 4, 4, 1, 2],
    [1, 3, 0, 0, 1],
]

plt.imshow(m)

plt.show()
```

This look like what I need, but the problem is that I need to be able to select the color for a position.

For example:

the position 1x2 has to be red.

anyway to archive this with Python and Pyplot?

Comment: Use RGB channels.. eg. your array has the shape `(rows, cols, channel)` and set each channel to the desired red, green, and blue value. So `m[1][2[0] = 255`

Comment: If 1x2 is red, do you want everything that has a value of `1` to be red as well?

Comment: @chrisz yes, something like that, if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can map a certain range to a certain colormap using the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments, and then assign those colors to particular values in your graph.  Here is a simple example, using the [`brg` cmap](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

I used 1-10 as a scale, so 1 will be Blue, 5 will be Red, and 10 will be Green, etc.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = [
    [1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 0],
    [0, 4, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 4, 4, 1, 2],
    [1, 3, 0, 0, 1]
]

dct = {1: 5., 0: 1., 2: 1., 3: 1., 4: 1.}
n = [[dct[i] for i in j] for j in m]
print(n)

plt.imshow(n, cmap='brg', vmin=1, vmax=10)
plt.show()
```

Output (All 1's in your matrix are now red, all other values set to blue):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess that `matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap` is what you need here:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = 'lime red blue magenta yellow'.split()
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors, name='colors', N=None)

m = [
    [1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 0],
    [0, 4, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 4, 4, 1, 2],
    [1, 3, 0, 0, 1],
]

plt.imshow(m, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

You may also use (R,G,B) tuples (instead of predefined color strings) in your list if you need more control

Comment: You might want to specifify how colors are picked for values, since this has position (1,2) as green. It seems like just a simple re-order of your listed color map.

Comment: @chrisz: The colors are simply mapped in order : 0 -> red, 1 -> lime, etc. So you need to provide one color for each different possible value in the range (five colors here). This is easy for matrices in an integer range domain as is the case here. If your domain is real values, other colormaps schemes are preferable

Comment: I'm saying that it is assigning 0-> red when he wants 1's as red. But I like this answer, if you have a fixed domain makes it very simple.

Comment: @chrisz: I edited the code (by switching 'red' and 'lime' so as 0 -> lime and 1 -> red. I don't know the desired colors for the other values...